# navigating from navigation controller to normal view controllers

Tags: iphone, modalviewcontroller, viewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have a navigation based view controller (root?) where I created (programatically) a home button  that takes the user to the main menu.

This main menu is a simple view controller and not part of the navigation controller.

To connect the two I have used the following code:

```
ViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainMenu"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Despite working, it just pushes the view controller on the stack with the navigation bar.

What I am trying to do is dismiss the navigation controller and return to the start.

I tried using the following code:

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

However I get the following crash: reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle

My question is how can I open another view controller programatically and dismiss the navigation controller? I cannot see the button so segues are not possible.

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this line:

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

in place of:

```
 ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use push on from `navigationContorller` then it push your view on stack , so you can do one thing, just hide your `navigatioBar` in viewWillAppear of your view.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```